# How to confirm if the Redis cluster is still being used before terminating?

Tags: redis

I have a Redis cluster that is still active and not sure if it is still been used. Logged in and tried command KEYS * and found around 30k+ keys.

How to identify if it is still been used if not can process to terminate?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use **KEYS** command in production, it can jam your Redis. Use **SCAN** instead.

If you mean you would like to know if some queries are still being made against Redis, you can use the [Monitor](https://redis.io/commands/monitor) command. Be careful though, it reduces your throughput by about 50%, so only use when necessary.